# Add Scrollbar to GridPane automatically - JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, gridpanel

I'm adding elements dynamically to a `GridPane` during excecution time, how can I allow scrollbar to be added automatically to this `GridPane`?

Related question : How to fix the cell width and height for all cells of the `GridPane`

Answer (score 2):

You could put the GridPane in a ScrollPane.